# How to remove mysterious white area in a vue app?

Tags: html, web, frontend, vuejs3

I'm trying to build a website with vue 3 and set a background picture for it. But there is a mysterious white area that can't be removed. I'm sure it's not margin or padding because I've set all the margins and paddings to 0, and removed all ml ,pl classes. I set the blackground color of the app component to black but the area it's still white. The chrome's inspect tool says it's a html element.Please give me a hand.(I put the backgroup picture in the style part of Login.vue.)

Information from browser's inspect tool:

[image: information from browser's inspect tool]

Inspect with pesticide:

[image: inspect with pesticide]

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- app.vue --!>
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app"
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

I put the backgroup picture in the style part of Login.vue.

```
<!-- Login.vue --!>
<template>
  <div class="body" id="poster">
    <el-form class="login-container">
      <el-card>
        <h4 class="login-title mb-2">Log in</h4>
        <el-form-item>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                 v-model="loginForm.username" placeholder="username"
          />
        </el-form-item>

        <el-form-item>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password"
                 v-model="loginForm.password" placeholder="password"
          />
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
          <el-button @click="login" type="primary"
                     style="width: 100%">Submit</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
      </el-card>

    </el-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import http from '../http'
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: 'login',
  data() {
    return {
      loginForm: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      },
      responseResult: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      const data = {
        username: this.loginForm.username,
        password: this.loginForm.password
      }
      http.post('/login', data)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(data);
            if (response.data.code === 200) {
              this.$router.push('/index')
            }
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          })
    }
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
.login-title {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
}
#poster {
  background: url("../assets/backgroud.jpg") no-repeat center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}
</style>
```

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from "./router";
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'



const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

```js
// router.js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        alias: '/login',
        component: () => import('@/components/Login.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/index',
        component: () => import('@/components/AppIndex.vue')
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router;
```

Comment: it's hard to say without being able to inspect it ourselves.  you should be able to use your browser's inspect tool and find an element that spans that area.  it may be a child element that's grown past the boundary of its parent, so you should try inspecting everything.  other than that, you also have two `<div id="app">` divs which you should also correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've just tried to remove the abundant <div id="app">, but it didn't work. Before posting this question, I used the inspect tool to check for margins and padding. The inspect tool indicates it's an HTML element, but I don't fully understand what that means. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to include a screenshot in the post.
Please click on this [hyperlink](URL) to view the screenshot and further inspect the element. Any additional insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which component do you use a background picture?

Comment: Pesticide is a good tool to inspect all divs on a page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bakpbgckdnepkmkeaiomhmfcnejndkbi

Comment: I put the backgroup picture in the style part of Login.vue.

Comment: "The inspect tool indicates it's an HTML element".  The inspect tool is actually indicating that it's currently focused on the `<html>` element of the page, which makes sense as it's the root element of the page and no other child element is currently receiving focus while you hover the inspect tool in that specific location.

Comment: Setting width of app components to max-content could make the blank area shrink, but not disappear.

Comment: I ran your code and found the problem to be with the `container` class.  I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of bootstrap class `container` wrapping your page content causes the max-width to be smaller than the full screen width.  The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/) shows the max-width values for each breakpoint.  Not only that, but bootstrap containers also have padding.

If you want to remove the empty space you should set the container width to 100% or use class name `container-fluid` which does the same thing, and also remove padding which you can do with class `p-0`

```html
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <router-view />
</div>
```

On a side note, I noticed you're using both Element Plus and Bootstrap, which are both large CSS/component frameworks.  It's very likely moving forward you'll run into a lot of frustrating conflicts between the two frameworks and their competing CSS styles. I suggest using only one of those frameworks!